# Flutter RefreshIndicator method is being called but the context is not rebuild

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I delete the item from the list, then I go back and refresh the page, RefreshIndicator seems not working(The animation is working but not refreshing the page). I have searched a lot about this problem. I tried everything I found on the web but none of them worked for me. The problem is that I have the method of `_refresh` to call this method `onRefresh` but it didn't work. I debugged the code to see whether the refresh method is being called. As far as I see it seems it is being called because I see `refresh method is called` on the debug console. The `ListView.builder` also has the `physics` property and it's not shrunk. I saw one more solution that suggests adding items that fill the whole screen. I added as many items as I can but it didn't work. So any suggestions? I am suspecting from the FutureBuilder that is a parent of the ListView.builder, I tried to cover the FutureBuilder too but it didn't work either.

```
class _DraftsState extends State<Drafts> {
  final SQFLiteHelper _helper = SQFLiteHelper.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('init state is called');
    super.initState();
    _helper.getForms();
  }

  Future<void> _refresh() async {
    print('refresh method is called');
    await _helper.getForms();
  }

//TODO: RefreshIndicator not working.
//TODO:When the list changed nothing is happening until the draft section is rebuilt
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<FormData>?>(
          future: _helper.getForms(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<FormData>?> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                  child: Text("Henüz kaydedilmiş taslak bulunmamaktadır."));
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                  child: Text(
                'Bir şeyler ters gitti.',
                style: TEXT_STYLE,
              ));
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return RefreshIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[700],
                color: LIGHT_BUTTON_COLOR,
                onRefresh: _refresh,
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return CustomListTile(
                          formData: snapshot.data![index], index: index);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<void> _refresh() async {
    print('refresh method is called');
    setState(() {
    await _helper.getForms();
    });
  }
```

use setState in your refresh function. coz you need to reload the build method. or I think you can use setState like this.

```
Future<void> _refresh() async {
    print('refresh method is called');
    await _helper.getForms();
    setState(() { });
  }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your attention. However, I have already tried the second method, and actually, it worked for me, but since we re-setting the state the refreshing is being interrupted which leads to a bad effect. I want the refreshing effect to be done after that the state should be refreshed. So, I tried using 'then()' but the same thing is happening. To sum up, I don't want the setState effect because if we use the setState no need to use RefreshIndicator because at the end of the day it does the same thing.

Comment: I think to understand your concern, in that case, you should use any state management like a provider or something else then you can separate your business logic from UI. then you don't need to use setState to update your value
[here you can find provider link](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)